# Ball probability question

Tags: probability

Suppose I drop $k$ balls into $N$ urns, with the probability a ball falls into any one of the urns equal.

What is the probability that any $q$ urns contain at least $m$ balls?  Note: I'm not looking for the probability that a specific combination of $q$ urns contains $m$ balls, but rather the probability that any combination of $q$ urns contains at least $m$ balls.

Comment: The probability of q specific urns getting at least m balls is relatively simple to compute, so I did try inclusion-exclusion to see something simple might fall out but it got really big really fast as you might expect.  I'm more hoping at this point that this problem has already been solved and that somebody can point me to an appropriate reference.

Comment: If you fill the urns, then select *any* $q$ of them, then the probability that they contain *at least* $m$ balls is the same as that for $q$ *particular* urns.  That is, as long as the selection is independent of the filling.

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of generality, rank the urns $U_i$ from most to least full.

The probability that $U_1$ contains more than $m$ balls is (from the [binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)):

$$P(U_1\ge m)=\sum_{i=m}^k{n\choose i}\frac{(k-1)^{n-i}}{k^{n}}$$

For the next urn, at least $m$ balls were used up in the first urn so:

$$P(U_2\ge m|U_1\ge m)=\sum_{i=m}^{k-m}{n-m\choose i}\frac{(k-1)^{n-m-i}}{k^{n-m}}$$

And in general,

$$P(U_j\ge m|U_{j-1}\ge m)=\sum_{i=m}^{k-(j-1)m}{n-(j-1)m\choose i}\frac{(k-1)^{n-(j-1)m-i}}{k^{n-(j-1)m}}$$

And therefore

$$P(U_q\ge m)=\prod_{j=1}^q\sum_{i=m}^{k-(j-1)m}{n-(j-1)m\choose i}\frac{(k-1)^{n-(j-1)m-i}}{k^{n-(j-1)m}}$$

This is the probability that *at least* $q$ urns contain $m$ balls. To get the probability that *exactly* $q$ urns contain $m$ balls you need to subtract $P(U_{m+1}\ge m|U_m\ge m)$.

This may or may not simplify - have fun.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was intrigued by the question, so here is my own version.

Suppose that the first $q$ urns contain $i$ balls, so the remaining $N-q$ urns contain $k-i$ balls. So, we want to find the probability the first $q$ urns contain *at least* $m\cdot q$ balls.

Then, we have the following:

$$ \displaystyle p=\sum_{i=m\cdot q}^k \dfrac {\dbinom{i+q-1}{i}\cdot \dbinom{ (k-i)+(N-q)-1}{k-i}}{\dbinom{k+N-1}{k}}$$

Some explanation:

$\dbinom{i+q-1}{i}:$ we shuffle $i$ identical elements (balls) in $q$ urns

$\dbinom{(k-i)+(N-q)-1}{k-i}$: we shuffle the remaining $k-i$ identical elements in the $N-q$ urns

$\dbinom{k+N-1}{k}:$ we shuffle $k$ identical elements in $N$ urns

It resembles **hypergeometric** distribution in a way.